# Do options in protobufs affect message sizes?

Tags: serialization, metadata, protocol-buffers

I am using protobufs to send messages between different nodes in a project, and for convenience, I would like to add some static metadata for my messages. For example, for each field in a message, I would like to define a human readable name (i.e. "Response Message" instead of "resp_msg") that GUIs can use as a label when displaying data. This information doesn't need to be serialized and transmitted over the wire.

I was looking to see if protobufs allow the defining of this metadata and I was pointed towards using custom options. It seemed to me that the custom options are internally implemented as additonal data inside of messages. Is this the case, or is it completely static metadata that doesn't get serialized when actually using those protobufs? i.e. if I add options to my messages, will the structure of my serialized messages change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean custom options *in the .proto schema*; no, those do not form part of the payload. They *may or may not* be available to inspect at runtime - it depends a lot on the specific library and tools that you are using, but: if the tooling for your target platform embeds the compiled `DescriptorProto` metadata (`DescriptorProto` maps roughly to `message` in .proto terms) into the generated code, then you may indeed be able to use an API to extract that data - or worst case: deserialize it into a `DescriptorProto` (as defined in `descriptor.proto`) and read it out manually.

This is not guaranteed, though.

So: it depends on both:

- what library, platform and tooling you are using
- whether your custom options extend things like `DescriptorProto`, vs extending your actual messages; if you are extending the actual messages with additional fields, that *is* part of the message payload and will increase message size